# Sort output of ls as per the date in the filenames

Tags: bash

I have group of files in a folder in following pattern `file_20230502181430` i.e.

```
file_$(date +"%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
```

What I want is to read all these files in an array to sort them by the date at the end i.e. `_$(date +"%Y%m%d%H%M%S")`, to keep the most recent 3 files and delete rest.

How can I sort an output of `ls file_*` according to dates at the end of file name and have them in an array to achieve what I want? If doing it with `ls` isn't possible, is there another or better way to do it?

Comment: Is the prefix always `file_`?  If so, then the normal `ls -l` should show them in date order.  You might consider using `logrotate` to handle these files.

Comment: `array=( file_* )`?

Comment: @TimRoberts yes prefix is always `file_`

Comment: @Cyrus is it always sorted according to the date in file name?

Comment: @Maven: yes, if you use `%Y%m%d%H%M%S`.

Comment: @Maven In general, the sort order that `file_*` produces can vary depending things like the current locale (see [this U&L question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/368318/does-the-bash-star-wildcard-always-produce-an-ascending-sorted-list)), but your filename pattern should come out date order in any sane situation. Importantly, the more-significant fields come first, and they use leading zeroes (without those, "1" and "10" might both come before "2"). So, yes, they'll be sorted by date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `bash`. I assume that the current directory contains the files mentioned.

```
# expand file_* with globbing to an array
names=( file_* )

# delete all files except the last (newest) three.
for (( index=0; index<${#names[@]}-3; index++ )); do
  echo rm "${names[$index]}";
done
```

If output looks okay, remove `echo`.

Answer (score 1):

check this out :

```
for file in $(ls -1 file_* | sort -t_ -k2 | head -n -3)
do
     echo "Deleting file: $file"
done
```

better approach

```
for file in file_*
do 
     echo "Deleting file: $file"
done | sort -t_ -k2 | head -n -3
```

Comment: Please note: [Why *not* parse `ls`?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)